# Is it possible to kill yourself with a throwing knife in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

So I noticed if I throw the throwing knife almost straight up, then it lands somewhere nearby.  I tried really hard to throw it up and then run ahead and have it land on me and kill me.  Is this possible, or will it not kill me?  If it is possible, is there a video of it somewhere?

Comment: The only question is why...

Comment: ...For teh lulz.

Comment: also, so people look at the killfeed and see someone killed by throwing knife two seconds after the game starts.  I have tube suicide down as well as tubing straight up to kill rushers on afgan and junkyard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various YouTube videos suggest not. [(1)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i35vaPKeGz4) [(2)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmcZApw_m-w)

I think if it were video evidence would be easy to find.

Comment: Ok... So it seems like you can in hardcore.  I'll try the favela barbershop window when I get home (from work).

Comment: Also try chucking it at the fortune teller on Carnival.